# How to get different class selectors using nth-child in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have these codes

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="tag1"></div>
    <div class="tag1"></div>
    <div class="tag1"></div>
    <div class="tag2"></div>
    <div class="tag2"></div>
    <div class="tag2"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to get second child of `.tag2` selector.

I try this code and it's not working, but when I use `.tag1` it's working.

```css
.test .tag2:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: `:nth-child` selector always works on element. There is no `nth-of-class` selector in CSS. Do you always want to select the second child with class as tag2 or is it only an example?

Comment: Yes, i always want to select the second child with class.

Comment: And do they come in groups (like the first is immediately before the second)? If yes you could use `.tag2 + .tag2` (I am sure this is a duplicate)

Comment: @Harry you'd have to specify the `.tag1` in that as well, otherwise it'd select all `.tag2` elements which follow other `.tag2` elements.

Comment: No, they may be like this: `<div class="tag1"></div>
    <div class="tag1"></div>
    <div class="tag2"></div>
    <div class="tag1"></div>
    <div class="tag2"></div>
    <div class="tag2"></div>`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yes true. I was editing it but since you commented I'll leave my previous comment as-is for context. Your comment is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:nth-child` works on elements, not on other selectors. Here your `.tag2` element is the 4th element in the list.

When browsers begin to implement the Selectors Level 4 standards we'll be able to achieve this using the `:nth-match` structural pseudo-class selector, but unfortunately that's quite a way off yet.

#### A Potential CSS Solution (Markup-dependant)

If your markup will always be that the first `.tag2` will only ever follow `.tag1` and the second `.tag2` will only ever follow `.tag2`, you can fake it with this:

```css
.tag1 + .tag2 + .tag2 {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

This selects the `.tag2` element which immediately follows a `.tag2` element which immediately follows a `.tag1` element.

#### A JavaScript Solution

If you can't do that then you'll have to go for a JavaScript solution instead (or implement something on the back-end which generates the content).

The below example pulls all `.tag2` elements within your `.test` container, then grabs the 2nd one (`[1]` here, remember the 0 index: `[1]` = 2nd), then applies the style to that element.

You'll need to add in some checks to ensure this element exists before applying the style.

```js
document.querySelector('.test').querySelectorAll('.tag2')[1].style.background = '#000'
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="tag1">tag1</div>
    <div class="tag1">tag1</div>
    <div class="tag1">tag1</div>
    <div class="tag2">tag2</div>
    <div class="tag2">tag2</div>
    <div class="tag2">tag2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna use the javascript part.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question isn't tagged with JavaScript, but a good solution with JS is as follows:

```js
var alltagtwos = document.getElementsByClassName("tag2");
alltagtwos[1].className += " secondel";
```

```css
.tag2.secondel {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="tag1">tag1 - 1</div>
    <div class="tag1">tag1 - 2</div>
    <div class="tag1">tag1 - 3</div>
    <div class="tag2">tag2 - 1</div>
    <div class="tag2">tag2 - 2</div>
    <div class="tag2">tag2 - 3</div>
</div>
```

What I've done here is add all elements with the class `.tag2` into an array-like object using `getElementsByClassName`. I then select the second element which has the class `.tag2` (index starts at zero, so I've select `[1]`) and appended another class to it (`.secondel`) which I've then styled with CSS.